# What is the best way to random 1000 row (not duplicate row) from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, random

What is the best way to random 1000 row (not duplicate row) from mysql ?

```
Now i use this
1. get all data(id row) in to array.
2. Random position of array 1000 position.
3. i will get 1000 row (not duplicate row)
```

But, it's very slow process,

Do you have easy way to get random 1000 row (not duplicate row) ?

Comment: Well if you don't show us your code we can only give you a theoretical answer, if you want this?

Comment: yes, or give me some ex code.

Comment: And what do you mean with *not duplicate row* Like that some column can't have the same value or the entire row can't be the same?

Comment: not duplicate row it's mean unique row ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from the comment you are also satisfied with a theoretical answer.

If you have your array with all rows, use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to get rid of duplicate rows then use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to mix them up and at the end you can take a slice with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

**EDIT:**

You can improve it when you already don't select duplicate rows, then you don't have to use `array_unique()`. For this use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html). And if you want to do all in a query you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: can i select from mysql with random  1000 unique row, by not use array ?

Comment: but it's not random ?

Comment: @robertderwe updated my answer when you want to do everything in the query

Comment: like this

`<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
echo $objResult[id];
echo "<br>";
}
?>`

Comment: @robertderwe yes, but I would not recommend you to use `mysql_*`

Comment: thank , but my site very large. it's not easy to change to mysqli. if i change to use mysqli , i have to test all function. It's very hard for me.

Comment: thank i have some question, that i know you can give me answer.

Comment: i want to know mysql can hack easy more than mysqli ?

Comment: @robertderwe Please use google, I'm not your personal lexicon